# Python: simple client server the listening for connections close after first connection close

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, client-server

So i want to build simple `Server-Client`.

This `server` gets connections from `clients` (simple `string`), do my stuff, return answer, close the client connection and wait for another connections.

**Client**

```
    import socket

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ip = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 4500
    address = (ip, port)
    message = 'mymessage'
    client = socket.socket()
    client.connect(address)
    client.sendall(message.encode('utf-8'))
```

**Server**

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
name = socket.gethostname()
ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = 4500
address = (ip, port)
server.bind(address)
server.listen(1)
print('Start listening on', ip, ':', port)
client, addr = server.accept()
print('Received connection from', addr[0], ':', addr[1])

while True:
    data = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print('Received', data, 'from the client')

    # DO something.....
    client.send('Goodbye'.encode('utf-8'))
    client.close()
    break
```

So currently after the `client` get back the response from the `server` the `server` is close and i want my `server` to continue listening for another connections.

Comment: So put the part starting with the `accept` into an outer loop? Use a thread for the inner loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, you need to add another loop, so that the server can always listen:

**Server**

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
name = socket.gethostname()
ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = 4500
address = (ip, port)
server.bind(address)
server.listen(1)

while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print('Start listening on', ip, ':', port)
    print('Received connection from', addr[0], ':', addr[1])
    while True:
        data = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print('Received', data, 'from the client')

        # DO something.....
        client.send('Goodbye'.encode('utf-8'))
        client.close()
        break
```